# about Java 8 Hashmap source： “+1.0F”

Tags: java

when I read the hashmap source 
code：`float ft = ((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F;` 
why need “+ 1.0F”？ it's necessary ？

```java
 final void putMapEntries(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m, boolean evict) {
        int s = m.size();
        if (s > 0) {
            if (table == null) { // pre-size   
                float ft = ((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F;   //  why +1.0F?
                int t = ((ft < (float)MAXIMUM_CAPACITY) ?
                         (int)ft : MAXIMUM_CAPACITY);
                if (t > threshold)             
                    threshold = tableSizeFor(t);  
            }
            else if (s > threshold)   
                resize();
            for (Map.Entry<? extends K, ? extends V> e : m.entrySet()) {
                K key = e.getKey();
                V value = e.getValue();
                putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, evict);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It could just be a formula.

Comment: It is not necessary, `+ 1` works just as well.

Comment: Did you mean 1) "Why `+1.0F` instead of  just `+1`"?; or 2) "Why `((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F` instead of just `(float)s / loadFactor`?"

Comment: mean： Why ((float)s / loadFactor) + 1.0F instead of just `(float)s / loadFactor'?

Comment: @KevinAnderson If you did a `+1` it would add one `Integer` which would then be promoted to a `Float` in the addition to the left hand side `float` value.  They reason they wrote `1.0F` is to tell the compiler that it is a `float` early, avoiding the eventual promotion of `int` to `float`.  Yes, it's a human optimizing for the needs of the compiler and runtime, but in some JVMs it really can make a difference.  `1.0d` is the `double` version, `1L` is the long version; but, there's no constant specifiers for "less than int" integer data types.

Answer (score 1):

The table needs to be reallocated when **entry_count > table_size * load_factor**.

If we solve for table size, we find that in order to ensure that a reallocation isn't required, we need **table_size >= entry_count / load_factor**.

This size is calculated in floating point, and the **1.0F** is added to ensure that the chosen table size will *still* be large enough after it is rounded down to an integer number of entries.